# Removing near identical values in a list of coordinates

Tags: javascript

I have a list of values similar to this:

```
[[100,100],[101,101],[101,103],[102,103],[104,101],[103,101],[542,121],[943,123]]
```

I'd like to reduce the near values to a single value - it can be an average, but I'm not tied to that specificity - while maintaining the unique values.

So from that example list, I'd like to get something like:

```
[[101,103],[542,121],[943,123]]
```

I've considered just dividing and rounding the values, getting rid of the repeating values, then multiplying them back to get to my scale, but that would give me a result of

```
[[100,105],[540,120],[945,125]]
```

and I'd like to maintain the uniqueness of the unique values.

Comment: I'd probably implement some kind of fuzzy set structure, and store values as `((a,b),n)` tuples, where `n` is the number of previously inserted `(a,b)` tuples so you can do a weighted average if you add the "same" element. The structure can accept a distance parameter `d` (calculated as `sqrt( (a-a1)^2 + (b-b1)^2) )`, under which values would be considered the "same."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say "similar" means "within 20 of the same center value" -- i.e. the set of all points that are within 20 of their combined center of mass. (20 is arbitrary and configurable, of course.) Then you can reduce the list like so (assuming the initial array is called `data`):

```
const threshold = 20;
const thresholdSq = threshold ** 2;
const groups = data.reduce((map, pair) => {
    let mini = Infinity, match = null;
    map.forEach(list => {
        const avg = list.reduce((sum, point) => {
            sum[0] += point[0];
            sum[1] += point[1];
            return sum;
        }, [].concat(pair));
        avg[0] /= 1 + list.length;
        avg[1] /= 1 + list.length;
        const distSquared = (avg[0] - pair[0]) ** 2 + (avg[1] - pair[1]) ** 2;
        if (distSquared < mini && distSquared <= thresholdSq) {
            mini = distSquared;
            match = list;
        }
    });
    if (match) {
        match.push(pair);
    } else {
        map.push([pair]);
    }
    return map;
}, []);
const result = groups.map(list => {
    const sum = list.reduce((acc, v) => {
        acc[0] += v[0];
        acc[1] += v[1];
        return acc;
    }, [0,0]);
    sum[0] /= list.length;
    sum[1] /= list.length;
    return sum;
});
```

For your example data, result becomes this:

`[[101.83333333333333, 101.5], [542, 121], [943, 123]]`

It's not exactly what the output you specified, but it does preserve unique values and give you the averages of the other groups of points.

Comment: I wrote a pretty similar implementation [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5bya92cv/), but then I realized that the order in which the elements are fed in could affect the end result. I think this has the same issue. You'd probably have to first sort the input to ensure a deterministic result even if the values are scrambled.

Comment: @NullUserException Skimming over your code, it looks like you're just checking the first element in each list to see if the current point is closer to it than the threshold. Mine checks the distance from the current point to the *average* center of mass of all the points in the list, including that new point. I think this prevents order from mattering, doesn't it? (Since the average doesn't depend on the order.)

Comment: Yeah, I think so. It's been a while since I've done JS

Comment: I just did a quick test by shuffling up the initial array many times and running the code. The order of input determines only the order of output, but not the actual groups or point values in it :)

Answer (score 1):

I already mentioned this in Slack, but what about generating a Voronoi diagram, then finding all cells that are smaller than some given value in area, and removing (N-1) of the points that make up the cell?

There might be some problems with edge cases where the cell is REALLY long, despite having a tiny area though...

Answer (score 1):

One idea could be to group first points into buckets, then you could do whatever you want with buckets, e.g. average them...

```
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.threshold = 5;
  }

  isSimilar(other) {
    return Math.abs(this.x - other.x) < this.threshold && Math.abs(this.y - other.y) < this.threshold;
  }

  avg(other) {
      return new Point(Math.round((this.x + other.x) / 2), Math.round((this.y + other.y)/2));
  }
}

var list = [new Point(100,100),
    new Point(101,101),
    new Point(101,103),
    new Point(102,103),
    new Point(104,101),
    new Point(103,101),
    new Point(542,121),
    new Point(943,123)];

var buckets = []

// Group similar points into buckets
list.map(function (p) {
    var bucket = buckets.find(function(b) { return b[0].isSimilar(p); });
    if(bucket == undefined) {
        buckets.push([p]);
    } else {
        bucket.push(p);
    }
});

// Here you could for example average each bucket
var avg = buckets.map(function(b) {
    return b.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.avg(b); });
});

console.log(avg);
```

Result:

```
[
  Point { x: 103, y: 102, threshold: 5 },
  Point { x: 542, y: 121, threshold: 5 },
  Point { x: 943, y: 123, threshold: 5 }
]
```

*NB: Using `class` indroduced by ECMAScript 2015...*